# Radius of convergence for power series of binomial expansion

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, power-series, binomial-theorem

Now I know that there are other questions on the radius of convergence for the power series of binomial expansion, but they do not answer my question.

I already know that the binomial exapansion is expressed as $$(1+x)^r = \sum_{n=0}^r\binom{r}{n}x^n$$

And the power series I am talking about is $$ f(x) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{r}{n}x^n = 1 + rx + {{r(r-1)\over2}x^2} + \dots$$

I think that this can also be written as $ lim_{r\to\infty}(1+x)^r $. The radius of convergence of the power series above is well known as 1. However, if I substitute $x=1/2$ in $ lim_{r\to\infty}(1+x)^r $, the limit does not converge which contradicts the fact that the radius of convergence is 1. Can anyone explain to me what's going on here? Thanks.

Comment: the second series must be wrong. What happens when n>r?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused. The generalized binomial expansion states that
$$(1+x)^r=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{r}{n}x^n$$
for $|x|\lt1$ where $r\in\mathbb{R}$. This also requires the definition
$$\binom{r}{n}=\frac{r(r-1)\cdots(r-n+1)}{n!}$$
With this definition we have that $\binom{r}{n}$ is zero when $n\gt r$ and $r\in\mathbb{N}_0$ which causes the summation to simplify to
$$(1+x)^r=\sum_{n=0}^r\binom{r}{n}x^n$$
when $r\in\mathbb{N}_0$.

Comment: @linearAlg See the same page but [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem)

Comment: I saw your section on the Wikipedia page:) thanks. I see how the generalization works. But if the power series is simply $(1+x)^r$ and r is not infinity, then can't we substitute any value for x and $(1+x)^r$ converges?

Comment: I don't understand this $r$ is infinity business. The value of $r$ is an arbitrary real number. Using any value of $x$ such that $|x|\lt1$ we will have convergence in this power series as stated in my answer.

Comment: reading the wikipedia page more thoroughly I understand your point. I was confused because I was unaware of the fact that for values of r other than nonnegative integers, the series has infinitely many nonzero terms.